# База данных и авторизация в отдельных классах , не получается подключить базу к другому классу

Tags: php

Подключение через PDO:

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=firstdatabase", 'root', 'root');
```

Класс базы данных

```
class DataBase {
    private $db;

    public function __construct(\PDO $pdo) {
      $this->db = $pdo;
    }
}
```

Класс с авторизацией

```
class User {
  public function AddUser($login, $password) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (login, password) VALUES (:login, :password)";
    $statment = $this->db->prepare($sql); // Что тут надо будет вписать объясните пожалуйста проблема в данной строчке
    $statment->bindParam(":login", $login);
    $statment->bindParam(":password", $password);
    $statment->execute();
  }
```

Я понимаю что нужно создать переменную которая будет принимать данный объект например:$dbhandle = new DataBase($db); но при реализации выдает ошибку, буду благодарен тому кто поможет исправить данную проблему , извиняюсь за тупость в коде я еще новичок ))

Comment: Текст ошибки нам надо угадать? В предыдущем вопросе твоём все было написано как делать. Зачем второй класс создаешь?

Comment: а смысл в один класс закидывать инфу про user'a и конструктор базу данных зачем(why)

Comment: Ну делай теперь в классе `User` конструктор и в него передавай объект класса `Database`. Стало проще?

Comment: Зачем тебе класс DataBase?